Understanding the Behavior of a Potentiometer in Gain Control for a Differential Amplifier
I’m studying a design of a differential input circuit where a potentiometer in the feedback loop controls the gain. I’m using the general gain formula for a differential operational amplifier. However, when adjusting the potentiometer, the common approximation (R1 = R3 and R2 = R4) no longer applies. I tried considering if the potentiometer’s value acts as a parallel resistance, but it doesn’t match the output voltage. Could you help me understand the behavior of this potentiometer? Thank you.
$$  V_{2} \left( \frac{R_1 + R_2}{R_1} \right) \left( \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} \right) - V_{1} \left( \frac{R_2}{R_1} \right)$$

R1 = 15k
R2 = 4K7 + RV 10k
R3 = 15k
R4 = 4K7



The output impedance of the opamp buffer in the feedback is 0, which means R2 = 4.7k and R1/R2 = R3/R4. Gain is A = 4.7k/15k * (4.8k+5.2k)/4.8k.

This way of controlling the gain disturbs the balance of the circuit.

Your expression for R2 is not correct because the additional circuit in the feedback loop (buffer plus potentiometer) must not simply added to the 4.7k resistor.
Without these additional components the feedback signal Hf at the inverting opamp input is determined by the opamp output voltage and the voltage divider 15k/(4.7k+15k) only.
However due to the voltage division at the potentiometr only a certain part of the output voltage is fed back (factor k<1).
It is the only purpose the buffer to decouple this additional part (potentiometr) from the classical feedback circuitry.
If you want to calculate the gain of the whole circuit you must take into account the actual feedback factor Hf=k*15k/(4.7k+15k).
Then, the known formulas for the opamps closed-loop gains can be used (opamp ideal):

Inverting: Acl=-Hi/Hf with input damping factor Hi=4.7/(4.7+15) and Hf as mentioned above.
Non-inverting: Acl=[4.7/(4.7+15)]*(1/Hf).

Final comment: In case you want to balance the circuit again, you must equalize both gain expressions (inverting and non-inverting)

Equations are "unmodified" excepted the voltage feedback \$v3=alpha * vo\$.
v3 is the voltage at the output of the upper opamp.
v1 is the voltage V3, v2 is the voltage V4.
Made with microcap v12.

Made with Maple.

Just see the coefficient \$ alpha \$ in the formula.

Initial observations
The way this circuit is designed is wrong. It is not possible to adjust the gain of the simple 1-op-amp differential amplifier by changing the value of only one component without disrupting the circuit's balance (common-mode rejection ratio). This can be done in the more complex 3-op-amp instrumentation amplifier circuit.
These were my initial concerns... but they turned out to be unfounded. Let's see why  by the help of the CircuitLab simulations below.
Fixed-gain differential amplifier
Initial state
Vin1 = 0 V, Vin2 = 0 V: It is obvious that all voltages in the circuit are equal to zero.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Common-mode
Vin1 = 10 V, Vin2 = 10 V: The circuit subtracts the two equal input voltages, weighted by their respective gains, and outputs the difference in accordance with the superposition principle. Since R1 = R3 and R2 = R4, the two gains are equal, and the output voltage is zero. So the circuit is balanced and does not react to the input common-mode voltage variations (try it in the simulation below by simultaneously changing both input voltages).

simulate this circuit
Differential mode
Vin1 + 100 mV, Vin2 - 100 mV: Let's now simulate a differential signal by increasing Vin1 by 100 mV and decreasing Vin2 by 100 mV...

simulate this circuit
Vin1 - 100 mV, Vin2 + 100 mV: ... and then by decreasing Vin1 by 100 mV and increasing Vin2 by 100 mV.

simulate this circuit
So, the circuit amplifies R2/R1 = 10 times the input differential voltage.
Variable-gain differential amplifier
A straightforward way to create a differential amplifier with variable gain is by simultaneously changing the resistance of resistors R2 and R4 (such as using a dual potentiometer). For instance, let's double the values of R2 and R4 (to 200 kΩ) and see the result.
Common-mode
Vin1 = 10 V, Vin2 = 10 V: The output voltage remains unchanged at 0 V (i.e., the circuit does not react to the input common-mode voltage variations).

simulate this circuit
Differential mode
Vin1 + 100 mV, Vin2 - 100 mV

simulate this circuit
Vin1 - 100 mV, Vin2 + 100 mV

simulate this circuit
So, now the circuit amplifies R2/R1 = 20 times the input differential voltage.
OP's variable-gain differential amplifier
The idea of the OP's circuit is to vary the circuit gain...
Simplified circuit
... by connecting (cascading) only one potentiometer after the op-amp output. Exploring the circuit in common mode, we observe satisfactory results (near-zero voltage).

simulate this circuit
Buffered circuit
To enhance the potentiometer's loading capability, an op-amp follower (buffer) OA2 has been added. The results were even better when we tested the circuit in another way.

simulate this circuit

Intriguingly, the simulation demonstrates successful circuit operation (common-mode input voltage rejection). There must be an ingenious design approach here. Clearly, further analysis is warranted...
Intuitive explanation
In the end, I managed to find a simple, intuitive explanation for the OP's circuit solution. It is nothing new, it can be found, for example, in an op-amp non-inverting amplifier circuit. The idea is as follows.
To make the original differential amplifier circuit change (increase) its gain, we can create additional difficulty (attenuation) in the negative feedback circuit by including a potentiometer. The op-amp reacts to this disturbance by increasing its output voltage Vout1 before the disturbance (point A in the circuits below). Thus it is compensated and the output voltage Vout2 after the disturbance (point B) is as in the original circuit without potentiometer. So, we use the amplified voltage Vout1 as an output instead Vout2 as before.
For the purposes of this intuitive explanation, let's simplify the circuit diagram a bit by increasing the resistance of the resistors, decreasing the resistance of the potentiometer, and removing the op-amp follower. Also, let's set the potentiometer's "gain"  in the middle (K = 0.5).
Common-mode
In this case (the same voltage Vcm at both inputs), both output voltages Vout1 and Vout2 are always zero, so the potentiometer plays no role.

simulate this circuit

Differential mode
Now there is an amplified voltage Vout1 at point A and "original" voltage Vout2 at point B. We take Vout1 as an output.

simulate this circuit
Conclusions

In the OP's circuit, the potentiometer (even when buffered) disturbs the circuit's balance, but the op-amp compensates for it by providing an additional "lift" to its output voltage, and we use it as an amplified output (similar to a non-inverting amplifier).

It turns out that the combination of the op-amp surplus output voltage, potentiometer, voltage follower, and R2 is ultimately equivalent to R2 alone, so the resistive balance is not compromised.



In oder to avoid misunderstandings: Of course, you can control the gain values using the above circuit with a pot - however, both gain values (inverting resp. non-inverting) will not change in the same manner and, therefore, the circuit will not simply amplify the difference between both input signals anymore (balance is destroyed). Instead, each input voltage will be amplified with another gain value.

@LvW, This is exactly my point.

The potentiometer is producing some fraction \$0 \le k \le 1\$ of the output. The voltage follower is therefore a voltage source with output \$V_C = k V_{OUT}\$, and the circuit can be drawn like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
$$ V_C = k V_{OUT} $$
With negative feedback the op-amp adjusts its output to whatever potential is required to equalise its two inputs:
$$ V_Q = V_P $$
R3 and R4 form a potential divider producing a fixed fraction of input \$V_A\$ at P:
$$ V_P = V_A \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} $$
R1 and R2 are also a potential divider, but node C isn't grounded, so the relationship between \$V_Q\$ and input \$V_B\$ isn't quite so simple. You'll find:
$$ V_Q = V_C + (V_B-V_C)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$
If it's not obvious why that's true, consider that the total potential difference between the two ends of the divider is \$(V_B-V_C)\$. Then recognise that R2 will have a "share" \$\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ of that total, and that voltage will be the difference between \$V_Q\$ and \$V_C\$. Hence the addition of an "offset" \$V_C\$.
There you have it, four independent simultaneous equations which you can combine and manipulate, to form a single equation for \$V_{OUT}\$, in terms of inputs \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$, and potentiometer position \$k\$.

There should be a simple intuitive explanation.

@Circuitfantasist Sometimes there isn't one. I couldn't see it, at least, except to say that feedback isn't some simple resistance here, because of the follower. The best I could muster was to point that out.

Simon Fitch, I think the difference between us is that you seek a balance between the formal and the intuitive, while I rely solely on the latter, sometimes taking it to extremes...

... I started to grasp the idea here after realizing that the potentiometer (even when buffered) disturbs the circuit's balance, but the op-amp compensates for it by providing an additional "lift" to its output voltage, and we use it as an amplified output (similar to a non-inverting amplifier). It turns out that the combination of the op-amp surplus output voltage, potentiometer, voltage follower, and R2 is ultimately equivalent to R2 alone, so the resistive balance is not compromised.
